# Strange behavior of the "find" command on RH

Tags: linux, find

on my Red Hat server I have a script inside the **/root/** folder that performs some operations based on the contents of some folders.
In particular

1. `find /PATH/TO_TEST/ -type f -name *.war` → search for war files from a certain folder
2. `find /PATH/TO_TEST/ -type d -name jobs`→ look for a folder with a certain name from a certain folder

Until yesterday everything worked properly, today a very strange thing happened (strange things happen at Hogwarts)

**Command 2** works normally.

**Command 1** only works if I **DO NOT** run it from within the `/root/` directory

That is if I execute the command while I'm in `/root/`, the find command doesn't give results while if I go out from `/root/` folder and go to any other folder the find command finds the files I'm looking for.

The path I look for is absolute, so the "where do I run the find command" should have no difference and HOWEVER, until yesterday it has regularly worked from inside the `/root/` directory.

on other similar vm everything works as it normally should.

The version of find command and the SO are the same in all VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote `'*.war'` to prevent the shell from expanding it:

```
find /PATH/TO_TEST/ -type f -name '*.war'
```

When it's unquoted, if there happens to be a `*.war` file in the current directory the shell will expand `*.war` to the name of that file. You want `find` to expand the glob, not the shell.

I'm guessing some `.war` file was recently dropped into `/root`. If there's a file `foobar.war` the unquoted version will expand to this terrible, horrible, no good, very bad command:

```
find /PATH/TO_TEST/ -type f -name foobar.war
```

Comment: Yes, exactly that!
I found a test war in the folder. I added the quotes and now the command works! Thanks!!!